# How to create field that is float but not double when doing Migrations?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, database-migration

I am using Laravel's migration system to recreate an existing database structure. The tables need to match the tables in this existing database exactly.

One of the fields on a table is described as so:

```
`frequency` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

Looking at the Laravel migration documentation I see the following options:

```
$table->float('amount', 8, 2);
$table->double('column', 15, 8);
```

Both of these column types results in creating a `double` type column with a length and decimal points. But I need one that is specifically defined as a `float` with no specified length and zero decimal points.

It it possible using Laravel's migration system?

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-tables) $table->float() creates a float field. What versions of Laravel / MySQL are you using?

Comment: No decimal points. Wouldn't that be an integer? By the way, there's also a decimal option, which is a bit more precise than a double.

Comment: I'm using the latest Laravel Homestead Vagrant instance. MySQL version is `5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`. Is this a bug? Because `->float('whatever')` is definitely creating a `double` column.

Comment: One google search and I found this (closed) Github issue about this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9103 - Seems like it's by design.

Comment: Yeah I just came across that. Really strange. MySQL has the FLOAT type there for a reason, even if a DOUBLE is technically the same thing.

Comment: Good luck getting anything useful out of GC. He could have at least looked into _why_ Taylor decided to make that change. Anyway, can't you get away with a double if you specify the precision?

Comment: I can't in this case. I have to recreate an existing legacy enterprise platform database structure that specifically uses FLOAT. The application checks it's Schema and the checks fail if it doesn't match exactly. Guess I need to resolve using raw SQL instead. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

It is kind of bug in laravel you can not make float type column, to make a column float use DB:statement and make sure to not write DB::statement in **Schema::create** it will throw an error because at that time table is not existed in database.

Write your DB:statement in **Schema::table** (Example code):

```
Schema::table('api_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            DB::statement('alter table `api_logs` add column `response_after` float null after request_at');
            DB::statement('alter table `api_logs` add column `query_time` float null after response_after');
        });
```

**upvote** this for better reach to laraverians.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` in MySQL.  That feature belongs only on `DECIMAL`.  If you want zero decimal places, use some form of `INT`.  On the other hand, maybe your `frequency` is in the gigahertz?  At which point `FLOAT` *without* precision or decimals, is the most appropriate.

Note that 1GHz will not fit in `FLOAT(8,2)`, but it will fit in `FLOAT`.

Why both?...  `FLOAT` takes 4 bytes; `DOUBLE` takes 8; both are part of the IEEE-754 standard that virtually every computer hardware implements.  In the "old" days (when 1MB of RAM was a "big" machine; the standard dates back to the early '80s), saving 4 bytes was a big deal.  If Laravel is turning float into double, that is its choice; MySQL will take either.

In virtually all situations `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` values and variables are interchangeable.  *But*...  A value stored in `FLOAT` and the same value stored in `DOUBLE` may lead to values that compare unequal.  For example, float(1.234) != double(1.234) in virtually all languages, hardware, etc.

MySQL is happy with  `frequency float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`.

But, if `$table->float('amount', 8, 2);` in Laravel means the same as MySQL's `FLOAT(8,2)`, then you are likely to have big problems.

`1234567.89` will be truncated to `999999.99`.  And `1.234` will be truncated to `1.23`, then rounded to binary.

Sounds like a bug report for Lavaral.  (Sorry, I have never used Lavaral, so I am guessing at its details.  I *do* know MySQL and IEEE-754.)